# Save counter in static html-page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a static html-page with no server-connection.

Is it possible to write a counter in javascript and save the current value of the counter somewhere beside the html-file?

Comment: You need to save it somewhere.. What do you mean you have no server connection? Where are your files hosted?

Comment: The html-file is located at a network-storage and directly called.

Comment: Maybe localStorage or a cookie?

Comment: If it is a counter for page visits, a cookie or localStorage won't be possible. @Tomtom is it a visitor counter?

Comment: Yes, it should be a visitor-counter

Answer (score 1):

You can make some requests on specific actions to another server (via ajax), which could save data.